# Keyboard hides form fields on mobile device, when user clicked on it or make focus on using React Js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, keyboard

I have created my web using React js. and if i access my web-app through a browser in mobile devices and web devices then if i press on one of field then Keyboard doesn't hide any field.

But when I access my web-app in Mobile devices through APK file using React-Native-Webview in android devices then Keyboard hides input fields.

Why this happen?

Any Solution ?

This is my React-native-code that i use my web-app convert in mobile APK.

```
<SafeAreaView
    style={{
      flex: 1,
    }}
  >
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: "https://renovationhub.my" }}
      onMessage={(event) => {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.data) // Client received data
      }}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
```